# How do I change nginx to direct Authentik to an external URL instead of an internal one?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am running nginx natively on my webserver, as I could not figure out how to use nginxproxymanager to serve as a reverse proxy for both my docker containers and my WSGI scripts. I recently tried installing Authentik after having difficulty with Keycloak and Authelia.

It *mostly* works well, except that it will use the internal IP address. That is to say, it does this:

1. I navigate to **app.domain.tld**
2. I am asked to authenticate at **192.168.0.x:23456/if/flow/default-authentication-flow/?next=<long GET string>**

Desired behavior is as follows:

1. I navigate to **app.domain.tld**
2. I am asked to authenticate at **auth.domain.tld/if/flow/default-authentication-flow/?next=<long GET string>**

Below are snippets of my nginx configuration file with addresses changed.

```
upstream auth {
    server localhost:23456; # Port number
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name auth.domain.tld;

        auth_basic off;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://authentik;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name app.domain.tld;

    auth_basic off;

    #if ($scheme = http) {
    #   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #}

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;

        auth_request        /outpost.goauthentik.io/auth/nginx;
        error_page        401 = @goauthentik_proxy_signin;
        auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
        add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;

        # translate headers from the outposts back to the actual upstream
        auth_request_set $authentik_username $upstream_http_x_authentik_username;
        auth_request_set $authentik_groups $upstream_http_x_authentik_groups;
        auth_request_set $authentik_email $upstream_http_x_authentik_email;
        auth_request_set $authentik_name $upstream_http_x_authentik_name;
        auth_request_set $authentik_uid $upstream_http_x_authentik_uid;

        proxy_set_header X-authentik-username $authentik_username;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-groups $authentik_groups;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-email $authentik_email;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-name $authentik_name;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-uid $authentik_uid;
    }

    location /outpost.goauthentik.io {
        proxy_pass        https://auth.domain.tld/outpost.goauthentik.io; # This results in  500 Internal Server Error
        proxy_pass        http://authentik/outpost.goauthentik.io; # This directs to 192.168.0.x:23456, the internal network IP of the server and the port specified above
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Original-URL $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
        add_header        Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
        auth_request_set    $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;

        # required for POST requests to work
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    }

    location @goauthentik_proxy_signin {
        internal;
        add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
        return 302 /outpost.goauthentik.io/start?rd=$request_uri;
        # For domain level, use the below error_page to redirect to your authentik server with the full redirect path
        # return 302 https://auth.domain.tld/outpost.goauthentik.io/start?rd=$scheme://$http_host$request_uri;

                # This also directs to 192.168.0.x:23456
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the forwarding headers in the nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

I think (in your current configuration) you are adressing the authentik outpost configuration - the authentik servers also need Websocket support.

You can find the official configuration guide for nginx reverse proxy (for authentik) here: https://goauthentik.io/docs/installation/reverse-proxy

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.

Should I be adding that snippet with the proxy_set_header changes to the `location /` subblock of my `app.domain.tld` block? I still get the original behavior described in my original post where it navigates to the original internal IP address.

Adding that same snippet to the `location /` subblock of my `auth.domain.tld` block results in 404 bad request errors when I try to go to `auth.domain.tld`